# How to use key press event to perform a calculation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii

This is my create page.

[image]

Rate = Labour + Machinery + Material + Site Over Head + Head office Over Head + Profit

Before the submit button click i want to done above calculation and fill it to the Rate text field. Is there a event like key press (Like in windows application) to do this ? 
I am new to yii and i think you guys help me to do this.

This is my form generated through the Yii.

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'trboq-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<?php
    $projectWbs = Yii::app()->session['projectWbs'];
?>

<?php
    $subBoqNo=Yii::app()->session['$subBoqNo']  ;
    $subBoqDes=Yii::app()->session['subBoqDes']  ;
    $mainBoqDes=Yii::app()->session['mainBoqDes']  ;
?>




    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>


<!-- Start of First table-->
 <div class="form">
  <div class="group" style="width:600px; padding-left:50px;margin-top:40px; margin-left:15px">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>General</legend>
      <table>
     <tr>
       <th><?php echo $form->hiddenfield($model,'Project_Code'); ?></th>
       <th><?php echo $form->hiddenfield($model,'Project_Code',array('size'=>20,'value'=>$projectWbs,'readonly'=>true)); ?></th>
       <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'Project_Code'); ?></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Sub_BOQ_No'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textField($model,'Sub_BOQ_No',array('size'=>20,'value'=>$subBoqNo,'readonly'=>true)); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'Sub_BOQ_No'); ?></th>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Sub_BOQ_Description'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textField($model,'Sub_BOQ_Description',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>150, 'value'=>$subBoqDes,'readonly'=>true)); ?>        </th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'Sub_BOQ_Description'); ?></th>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'BOQ_Item_Code'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textField($model,'BOQ_Item_Code',array('size'=>25,'maxlength'=>25)); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'BOQ_Item_Code'); ?></th>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'BOQ_Item_Name'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textarea($model,'BOQ_Item_Name',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>40)); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'BOQ_Item_Name'); ?></th>
    </tr>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'BOQ_Description'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textarea($model,'BOQ_Description',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>40)); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'BOQ_Description'); ?></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Unit_Code'); ?></th>
        <th> <?php echo $form->dropdownlist($model,'Unit_Code',CHtml::listData(MaUnits::model()->findAll(),'Unit_Code','Unit_Code'),array('width'=>              '25', 'empty'=>'please select'));  ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'Unit_Code');?></th>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Qty'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textField($model,'Qty'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'Qty'); ?></th>
    </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>

  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form">
  <div class="group" style="width:600px; padding-left:50px;margin-top:40px; margin-left:15px">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Cost</legend>
      <table>
      <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Labour'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textField($model,'Labour'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'Labour'); ?></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Machinery'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textField($model,'Machinery'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'Machinery'); ?></th>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Matirial'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textField($model,'Matirial'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'Matirial'); ?></th>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Side_over_head'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textField($model,'Side_over_head'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'Side_over_head'); ?></th>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Head_office_over_head'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textField($model,'Head_office_over_head'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'Head_office_over_head'); ?></th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Profit'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textField($model,'Profit'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'Profit'); ?></th>
    </tr>
    <tr><th><p>----------------------------------------------------------------------------</p></th></tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Rate'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textField($model,'Rate'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'Rate'); ?></th>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Amount_Total'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->textField($model,'Amount_Total'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $form->error($model,'Amount_Total'); ?></th>
      </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  </div>

        <div class="row buttons" style="margin-left:580px">
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Save' : 'Save'); ?>
        </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this kind of thing with javascript and jquery, take a look at how it works on: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/, http://www.w3schools.com/js/, http://api.jquery.com/

It takes some work getting to know javascript but you can build powerfull things with it.

in your case, it could be somethig like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
            <input id="Labour" type="text"/> <label>Labour</label> <br/>
            <input id="Machinery" type="text"/> <label>Machinery</label> <br/>
            <input id="Material" type="text"/> <label>Material</label><br/>
            <input id="Site" type="text"/> <label>Site Over Head</label><br/>
            <input id="HeadOffice" type="text"/> <label>Head Office Over Head</label><br/>
            <input id="Profit" type="text"/> <label>Profit</label><br/>
            <input type="submit">  <br/>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#myForm input").each(function(){
                $(this).keyup(function(){
                    var labour = $("#Labour").val();
                    var Machinery = $("#Machinery").val();
                    var Material = $("#Material").val();
                    var SiteOverHead = $("#Site").val();
                    var HeadOfficeOverHead = $("#HeadOffice").val();
                    labour = $.isNumeric(labour)?labour:0;
                    Machinery = $.isNumeric(Machinery)?Machinery:0;
                    Material = $.isNumeric(Material)?Material:0;
                    SiteOverHead = $.isNumeric(SiteOverHead)?SiteOverHead:0;
                    HeadOfficeOverHead = $.isNumeric(HeadOfficeOverHead)?HeadOfficeOverHead:0;
                    $("#Profit").val(parseInt(labour)+parseInt(Machinery)+parseInt(Material)+parseInt(SiteOverHead)+parseInt(HeadOfficeOverHead));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for replying. but in my case i want to calculate the rate before the submit button click. when user enter the Labour, Machinery ect ... rate must calculate the same time of above values entered. (Like Ajax validation)

Comment: That is what the .change() event is for. but if you want it to happen on a key up you should take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: Thank you for the replying. I tried this. it doesn't work. i include the my form above.